# How can i change on MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

i have like

> `https://localhost:12345/en/Dashboard`

and i have `@item.code="gr"` and I want to replace in here 'en' with 'gr' how can i do that in html

```
<a href="@Url.Path.Replace($"/{currentlangugage.code}", $"/{item.code}")>
```

What is the correct one and this code in cshtml file. How can i do that easily on my View? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You should be using `IUrlHelper.Action` (and other methods) instead of `String.Replace`.

Comment: can't understand that

Comment: See the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821941/generating-link-using-urlhelper-in-mvc-6-controller-vnext

Comment: i already see it but i want to find $"/{currentlangugage.code}" in the current url and just want to replace with $"/{item.code}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on replacing part of the URL you should think about using a regular expression to identify specifically the current language code at the beginning of the URL's path.

Stick this in your view somewhere

```cs
@functions{
    public string ReplaceLang(string path, string currentCode, string newCode) {
        var langRegex = new Regex($"(?<=^/){currentCode}");

        return path.Replace(path, newCode);
    }
}
```

Then use it something like this

```
<a href="@ReplaceLang(Context.Request.Path, currentlangugage.code, item.code)")>
```

Comment: i need to do that on my View and need to more simple one row code

Comment: _"...need to more simple one row code"_ Why? Stick it in a helper!

Comment: I cant write this code in my View

Comment: I have updated my answer to just deal with the path of the URL

Comment: 'IUrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Path' and no accessible extension method 'Path' accepting a first argument of type 'IUrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Cant found @Url.Path

Comment: @ruhatozcan You put it in your question and I just copied it! Try `@Context.Request.Path` instead.